# using lists inside multirow

Tags: tables, lists, multirow

I want to use a multirow item list in a column of a table, but it does not work. it says an \item is missing but it already ended before.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%definir a fonte a utilizar
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent
\tabulinesep=1.5ex
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|X[m,c]}
\cline{0-1}
Autorizado & & \multirow{2}{*}{
    \begin{description}
        \item[First] The first item
        \item[Second] The second item
        \item[Third] The third etc \ldots
    \end{description}
}\\\cline{0-1}
Não Autorizado & \\\cline{0-1}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}`
```

**UPDATE**
I have done it using a box, but now i have another issue. The table is vertical aligned to middle (m), and in this cell i need it to be aligned to TOP. Not the box, but the multirow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%definir a fonte a utilizar
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent
\tabulinesep=1.5ex
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|X[m,c]}
\cline{0-1}
Autorizado & & \multirow{2}{*}{
\parbox[t][][t]{4cm}{
\small
\begin{description}
\item[First] The first item
\item[Second] The second item
\item[Third] The third etc \ldots
\end{description}
}
}\\\cline{0-1}
Não Autorizado & \\\cline{0-1}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to pass a width to `\multirow` if you want to typeset a list in it; or you can set the `description` inside a `minipage` environment.

Comment: Thanks! I have made it in other way, i'll update it. Ofcourse with other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking of your question. Why do you even want to have a `description` INSIDE a `tabu` cell?! If your answer is "to have it beside the table" or "I use the `tabu` for text alignment" please consider the following alternative. The output looks like the same, but requires much less tinkering.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\tabulinesep=1.5ex
\begin{tabu} to 0.66\linewidth [t] {|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|}
\firsthline
Autorizado & \\
\hline
Não Autorizado & \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
    \begin{description}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
        \item[First] The first item
        \item[Second] The second item
        \item[Third] The third etc \ldots
    \end{description}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well ... that's it ... that 0.66 is the true answer. I am new to latex, so i was also unable to remember the minipage.

Comment: @user2674293 No problem. I'm quite new to `LaTeX` as well. Sometimes when I ask a question someone (most of the times egreg) points out that what I'm trying to achieve is a huge overkill and the original task can be done in a "more tex" way (which is often shorter too). That's why I dared to add this answer. And your question triggered an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142786/36821) which IMHO has really useful info.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your `description` in a `minipage`; with the help of `enumitem` you can remove the space between items (if desired). There's no need to guess the width of the minipage, because you can use `\hsize`.

Note that I removed the `m` specifier in the third column or you will never get top alignment.

This is a rare case where `\multirow` can benefit, although the purpose is not very clear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array,multirow,enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\tabulinesep=1.5ex
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|X}
% some cells to show the effect
\hline
A & B & C \\
\hline
% now an empty row
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
% here starts your table
\cline{0-1}
Autorizado & & \multirow{2}{*}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
    \begin{description}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
        \item[First] The first item
        \item[Second] The second item
        \item[Third] The third etc \ldots
    \end{description}
  \end{minipage}%
}\\\cline{0-1}
Não Autorizado & \\\cline{0-1}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Note that I removed the m specifier in the third column or you will never get top alignment." - you said it all. and in this case ... i can change the align to top ... but if you wanted this to one one cell it would not be possible, right?

Comment: @user2674293 I don't know precisely; and I'm not keen on burning my eyes looking at `tabu`'s documentation.

Comment: @egreg Your code is identical to the MWE of the asker. Is it on purpose? (Or am I missing sg?)

Comment: @egreg I don't think this is aligned to top (even with the `m` and `x` removed). Should it be?

Comment: I mean: a `[t]` is missing from `tabu` and a `\firsthline` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For information, you can put a `{description}` in a `\Block` in an `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,xcolor,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|X[m,c]|X[m,c]|X[m,c]}
\cline{1-2}
Autorizado & & 
\Block{2-1}
  { 
    \begin{description}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
        \item[First] The first item
        \item[Second] The second item
        \item[Third] The third, etc.
    \end{description}
  }
\\
\cline{1-2}
Não Autorizado \\
\cline{1-2}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]